# How to alias the methods in a Groovy Category class

Tags: groovy, dsl

I created a class: `NumberHelper`

it has method: `roll(num)`

and I want to alias it, such as `rollOnce`, so I wrote:

```
static def rollOnce = NumberHelper.&roll
```

And the  program throw an exception when I call `rollOnce`.
How to do this in groovy?

More Detail:

First, we implement Number class for our own business, in Java

```
    def userBuildScript = findScript(name) as Closure
    use (NumberHelper, StringHelper, UserHelper){
        // first make the user object
        // then
        userBuildScript.call(preBuildUser, businessNumberObject)
    }
```

and we wrote a category class for our Number class, it is the NumberHelper above.

and in the build script:

```
    user(someRole) { user, number ->
         it.someProperty = number.roll() // here, an exception throw
    }


    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: xxx.xx.x.user.biz.Number,roll() is applicable for argument types
```

are these info enough to help me find the reason?

And thanks for answering, thanks:)

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace. And source code would be helpful too.

Comment: Where/how are you defining `rollOnce`? If `roll` is static, and you remove the `static` keyword for `rollOnce`, it works fine--we need more context.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work as long as the original roll method is also static.  This works fine for me in groovy 1.8.6:

```
class NumberHelper {
    static def roll(num) {
        return new Random().nextInt(num) + 1
    }

    static def rollOnce = NumberHelper.&roll
}

def roll = NumberHelper.roll(6)
assert roll <= 6 && roll >= 1

rollOnce = NumberHelper.rollOnce(10)
assert rollOnce <= 10 && rollOnce >= 1
```

Comment: Ah, missed that in the title, yeah we need to see the code to know what the OP is doing.